# Replace a json value with the key

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a json list in which I need to change the **columnDataType** key with the regexp below. For example , the **char** becomes **select** after the regexp test given in the replecement object .

```
const list = [ 
    {
        "a": {
            "columnName" : "a",
            "columnDataType": "char",
            "columnType": "categoricalValues",
            "categoricalValues": [
                "Pre",
                "Post"
            ]
        },
        "b": {
            "columnName" : "b",
            "columnDataType": "int",
            "columnType": "range",
            "categoricalValues": [],
            "range": {
                "min": "1",
                "max": "250"
            }
        },
        "c": {
            "columnName" : "c",
            "columnDataType": "date",
            "columnType": "value",
            "categoricalValues": []
        },
        "d": {
            "columnName" : "d",
            "columnDataType": "categoricalValues",
            "columnType": "value",
            "categoricalValues": [
                "TRUE",
                "FALSE"
            ]
        }
    }
];

const replacements = [
  { criteria: /^(char.*\([0-9]{0,5}\)|char|varchar)$/, replacement: "select" },
  { criteria: /^(int|integer|.{1,}int|(numeric\(\d{1,2},\d{1,2}\))|number|decimal)$/, replacement: "range" },
  { criteria: "boolean", replacement: "select" },
  { criteria: /^date.*$/, replacement: "date" },
  { criteria: /^time.*$/, replacement: "date" }
];
```

Comment: So? what's the question ?

Comment: How to convert the columnDataType value to the replacement value with regexp

Comment: Please see this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through keys and find needed:

```js
function replace(list, replacements) {
  return replacements.reduce(replaceOne, list);
}

function replaceOne(list, replacement) {
  return Object.entries(list).reduce(replaceValue(replacement), list);
}

function replaceValue({ criteria, replacement }) {
  return (list, [ key, value ]) => {
    if (! criteria.test(value.columnDataType)) {
      return list;
    }

    return {
      ...list,
      [key]: {
        ...value,
        columnDataType: replacement
      }
    }
  }
}
```